# You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity in relativelayout image using glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using relativelayout to set an image.Why I hadn't using imageview means, inside relativelayout image, I am setting icons.

I dont know what is the issue exactly in glide.I have posted the stacktrace and relevant code below:

**Logcat:**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.app.steve, PID: 15928 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
   at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:134)
   at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:102)
   at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:644)
                                                                    at com.app.steve.TabMorePagesDetailActivity$allPageDetails.onPostExecute(TabMorePagesDetailActivity.java:1050)
     at com.app.steve.TabMorePagesDetailActivity$allPageDetails.onPostExecute(TabMorePagesDetailActivity.java:885)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**TabMorePagesDetailActivity.java:**

```
RelativeLayout rlPageCoverImg;

rlPageCoverImg = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_club_cover_img);

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);

            dialog.dismiss();
        ............

    String coverIMGurl = cover_avatar_obj.getString("url");

    Log.e("ImgURL", coverIMGurl);

 Glide.with(TabMorePagesDetailActivity.this).load(coverIMGurl).asBitmap().signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(500, 500) {

    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resource);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                            rlPageCoverImg.setBackground(drawable);
    }
    }
    });

    }else {

    rlPageCoverImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_golive);

    }



    @Override
 protected void onDestroy()
 {
    super.onDestroy();
    Glide.clear(rlPageCoverImg);

 }
```

**layout.xml:**

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_club_cover_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cancel_image" >

  // Inside this relativelayout image, I'm using buttons and icons


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

**Use:**

`Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(...)`

**Instead of:**

`Glide.with(TabMorePagesDetailActivity.this).load(...)`

Hope it will solve your problem~

**BEWARE**: See [Glide image loading with application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964737/glide-image-loading-with-application-context/32887693#32887693) if you decide to use `applicationContext`

Comment: Also fixed this by getting and using the ApplicationContext:                         

Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                                .load(storageReference)
                                .signature(new StringSignature(uri.toString()))
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .placeholder(placeHolder)
                                .into(imageView);

Comment: This will stop it from crashing, but will still use the resources to load the image even if the activity has been destroyed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887693/389649 for why using your application context in Glide isn't a good idea.

Comment: I have tried to use your solution but my app is crashing

Comment: Using application context (unless required) totally destroys the purpose of Android's context model. System decides which resource to release or to keep in memory, to execute or keep around based on the affiliated context. Finished Activity should release its resources.

Comment: This answer will fix your crash... at the expense of performance. See below for the proper answers

Comment: it's not a solution!

Comment: Not a good solution. You should use https://stackoverflow.com/a/60368532/5695458

Comment: You would start getting a lot of outOfMemory errors. Be careful using this solution. You would get rid of the crash, though the in-memory cache would be always alive until your appcontext is alive. Glide is clearing it's mem-cache when context dies. so identify in which particular container your data should live and choose activity, fragment or whatever context you need.

Answer (score 19):

Inspired from a GitHub [thread](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/803), I am using this before loading any image

```
final Context  context = getApplication().getApplicationContext();

if (isValidContextForGlide(context)){
                // Load image via Glide lib using context
               
  }

 public static boolean isValidContextForGlide(final Context context) {
    if (context == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        if (activity.isDestroyed() || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can simply check the context is destroyed or not manually as;

```
if (context == null) {
    return
} else if (context !is Application) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        if (context is FragmentActivity) {
            if ((context as FragmentActivity).isDestroyed) {
                return
            }
        } else if (context is Activity) {
            if ((context as Activity).isDestroyed) {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can also be represented as a Kotlin extension function:

```
/**
 * Return true if this [Context] is available.
 * Availability is defined as the following:
 * + [Context] is not null
 * + [Context] is not destroyed (tested with [FragmentActivity.isDestroyed] or [Activity.isDestroyed])
 */
fun Context?.isAvailable(): Boolean {
    if (this == null) {
        return false
    } else if (this !is Application) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            if (this is FragmentActivity) {
                return !this.isDestroyed
            } else if (this is Activity) {
                return !this.isDestroyed
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Isn't FragmentActivity an Activity?

Answer (score 10):

Please do not use `Glide.with(getApplicationContext())` unless you really need to, for reasons discussed here:
[Glide image loading with application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964737/glide-image-loading-with-application-context/32887693#32887693)

The correct answer is outlined here:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1484#issuecomment-365625087

In Kotlin, that can be written as an extension function:

```
fun Context.isValidGlideContext() = this !is Activity || (!this.isDestroyed && !this.isFinishing)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have got the same issue before few days.I have solved this to passing the Application context memory behalf of current Class context memory.

May be it will help you :-

**use this code**

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
           .load(coverIMGurl)
           .asBitmap()
           .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(500, 500) {....}
```

Even you are getting this issue then read this article carefully "https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1097"

***overview for this issue : This is an issue of Glide library.***

Comment: what to do if it is fragment..?

Comment: getActivity().getApplicationContext(); @Abhishek

Comment: Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component                                                                               @Abhishek In case of fragment you need to use getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: How to do it in recyclerview then?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO pass with constructor of recyclerview adapter   for example Adapter adp = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),list_of data), and use that in adapter.

Comment: that context is getting used in resources. Why would I pass application Context there?

Comment: "https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1097    check this one you will get your answer.

Comment: Guys using application context is not a good idea here. In case your activity is destroyed it still want to load the image. This is not the right way

Comment: it's not a solution!

Answer (score 4):

Try this before load your image with Glide, in my case mirefer is a StorageReference, miimagen is a ImageView. I solved this problem, with this. I hope it could help you.

```
if (!this.isFinishing ()) {
                // Load the image using Glide
                Glide.with(YourActivity.this)
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(mirefer)
                        .into(miimagen);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup Glide with a parameter which has the correct lifecycle. For example: use `Glide.with(this)` instead of `Glide.with(getContext())` in a custom view.

Comment: this way you init glide for each item view holder, I don't think it's good for performance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Kotlin extension that puts together a few answers above - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47980130/4559141), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60368532/4559141), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682571/4559141):

```
/**
 * Returns true when [Context] is unavailable or is about to become unavailable
 */
fun Context?.isDoomed(): Boolean = when (this) {
    null -> true
    is Application -> false
    is Activity -> (this.isDestroyed or this.isFinishing)
    else -> false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't just use context in adapter which you take from activity as context=this
rather use context.getApplicationContext();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

the other way is to check if the activity is destroyed or not, then load into UI element.

```
if (!newActivty.isDestroyed()){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi in view model for frament
The activity context is kept even when you press the back button and exit the program.
And go back to the program, you do not need to re-value the context because the context is static

```js
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final viewholder viewholder, final int i) {
        final Model_Post model_post = list.get(i);
        Log.e(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+model_post.getImageurl());

        Glide.with(MainActivity.activity)
                .load(Uri.parse(model_post.getImageurl()))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(viewholder.itemsPostBinding.imgvItempost);

    }
```

You must do this in main activity :

```
public static AppCompatActivity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = MainActivity.this;
}
```

Comment: No no no. You should never store activity as a static variable. This will cause memory leaks. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: So how do I set the context in the adapter to use glide? My glide is in an adapter in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Pls use Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load.......
It has solved my issue ref https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2690

Comment: this way you init glide for each item view holder, I don't think it's good for performance

Answer (score 0):

Just use this helper class:

```
/**
 * @Lukas Niessen
 */
public class GlideUsus {

    public static final String TAG = "GlideUsus";

    public interface Interface {
        void doIfValidContext(RequestManager requestManager);
    }

    public static void execute(Context context, GlideUsus.Interface action) {
        if (isValidContextForGlide(context)) {
            action.doIfValidContext(Glide.with(context));
        } else {
            // nothing
            Log.v(TAG, "Loading image failed");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidContextForGlide(final Context context) {
        if (context == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            if (activity.isDestroyed() || activity.isFinishing()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GlideUsus.execute(mContext, (a -> a.load(uri).into(image)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Glide provides so many `.with()`  methods for a reason: it follows lifecycle.

Imagine a Fragment that is dynamically added to an Activity. In its onCreateView method it starts a Glide load of a 3MB image. Now, what if the user presses the back button and the Fragment is removed or the whole activity is closed?

- If you use `with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())` nothing will happen, all 3MBs of data is downloaded and then decoded, cached, probably even set to the ImageView, which is then garbage collected, because the only reference to it was from Glide internals.
- If you use `with((Fragment)this)` Glide subscribes to the Fragment's lifecycle events and as soon as the Fragment is stopped, the any outstanding request should be paused; and when destroyed, all pending requests be cleared. This means that the image download will stop midway and no more resources will be used by that dead Fragment.
- If you use `with(getActivity())` Glide subscribes to the Activity's lifecycle events and the same thing happens as above, but only when the Activity is stopped or destroyed.
- If you use `with(view)` Glide will do the same as in with `(view.getContext())`  which is equivalent to the Activity case just above.

So the best practice is to use the closest possible context/fragment to avoid unused request completions! (There's also a manual way to stop a load: Glide.clear(ImageView|Target).)

---

To apply this in practice try to use with(this) when possible, but when it's not, like in an adapter, or a centralized image loading method, pass in a RequestManager glide as an argument and use glide.load(...,

for example:

```
 static loadImage(RequestManager glide, String url, ImageView view) {
    glide.load(url).into(view);
}
```

or in adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends WhichEveryOneYouUse {
    private final RequestManager glide;
    MyAdapter(RequestManager glide, ...) {
        this.glide = glide;
        ...
    }
    void getView/onBindViewHolder(... int position) {
        // ... holder magic, and get current item for position
        glide.load... or even loadImage(glide, item.url, holder.image);
    }
}
```

and use these from Activity/Fragment:

```
loadImage(Glide.with(this), url, findViewById(R.id.image));
// or
list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(Glide.with(this), data));
```

Answer (score -2):

In activity I use **`Glide.with(getApplicatonContext())`** and
in adapter I use **`Glide.with(myContext.getApplicatonContext())`**

```
//It works for me fine.

//for adapter

Context myContext;

//also initilize in `oncreateViewHolder`

@Override
    public MessagesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_messages_layout, parent, false);
        myContext = parent.getContext();
        return new MessagesHolder(view);
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use application context with `Glide.with`, here is the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32887693/6074224