# cannot start a load for a destroyed activity

Tags: android, android-glide, ondestroy

Hello i am having this problem

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
```

I have tried the method other I did during this error but none of them are working. In my case, when my app starts, in its main activity a video is being loaded. When i press back button during that video is being load, my app crashes. Can somebody please help me?

This is my on destroy method

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).pauseRequests();
        super.onDestroy();
}
```

Log:

```
10-10 12:33:09.294 752-824/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=2437 BSSID=c8:50:e9:0f:10:fa RSSI=-44 "nirc1"WPA_PSK
10-10 12:33:09.628 15936-15936/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:134)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:102)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:87)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:657)
    at com.freesoulapps.preview.android.Preview$7$3.run(Preview.java:277)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
10-10 12:33:09.690 1803-15644/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
10-10 12:33:10.087 15936-15936/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: Can you post your entiire Logcat please

Comment: Sure. Please look at it. I just posted

Comment: Check out my solution. Try it.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093730/you-cannot-start-a-load-for-a-destroyed-activity-in-relativelayout-image-using-g

Comment: actually  the function onDestroyed is not being executed

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

You must use `your_activity_name.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` and `isDestroyed()` as shown below:

```
@override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

    if (!this.isDestroyed()) {
         Glide.with(your_activity_name.this).pauseRequests();
    }

}
```

Try it. Hope it helps.

Comment: i think the problem is on the api below 24

Comment: Hmm, Then put a check in the same if condition and try @Sudeep

Answer (score 1):

Validate first for check weather your current class context is available or not before do on `onDestroy()` method.

```
@override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

    if (!this.isFinishing ()) {
         Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).pauseRequests();
     }
    }
```

For more have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093730/you-cannot-start-a-load-for-a-destroyed-activity-in-relativelayout-image-using-g)

Comment: i tried the above method bro. the error is still same :(

Comment: did you debug the code and check point reach inside if condition ?

Comment: actually the function onDestroyed is not being executed

Answer (score 0):

if you use getApplicationContext() while initializing
the glide as Glide.with(getApplicationContext()) and pause all request by overriding 
onDestroy() as

```
@override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).pauseRequests();
}
```

Comment: have u tried my code call super.ondestroy before Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).pauseRequests();

Comment: Have u initialized glide : Glide.with(getApplicationContext())