# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, instrumentation, android-instrumentation

I try to do Instrumentation Test in my project but it have an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity

This is my error :

```
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:88)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:314)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:297)
at com.example.riken.footballmatch.view.HomeActivityTest.testFootballMatchBehaviour(HomeActivityTest.kt:40)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131230965, res-name=tvTeam_home_detail, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=46, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@1c6b0fe, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=117.0, y=168.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:539)
at android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$MatchesViewAssertion.check(ViewAssertions.java:103)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:415)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:279)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:323)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:132)
at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:723)
at com.example.riken.footballmatch.view.DetailActivity.showAwyLogo(DetailActivity.kt:108)
at com.example.riken.footballmatch.presenter.MatchDetailPresenter$getAwayLogo$1.invokeSuspend(MatchDetailPresenter.kt:40)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:235)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractContinuation.run(AbstractContinuation.kt:19)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)

Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'
```

DetailActivity.kt

```
package com.example.riken.footballmatch.view

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.R
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.R.id.add_fav_fragment
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.api.ApiRepository
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.database.database
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.extension.gone
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.extension.visible
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.model.FavoriteItem
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.presenter.MatchDetailPresenter
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.model.Team
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.team.detmatch.MatcDetView
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.model.MatchActivity
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_detail.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.classParser
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.delete
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.insert
import org.jetbrains.anko.db.select
import org.jetbrains.anko.design.snackbar

class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MatcDetView {

    private var matchdet: MutableList<MatchActivity> = mutableListOf()
    private var idEvent: String? = ""
    private var idTeamHome: String? = ""
    private var idTeamAway: String?  = ""
    private lateinit var matchpresenter: MatchDetailPresenter
    private lateinit var progresbar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var swipeRefresh: SwipeRefreshLayout
    private var menuItem: Menu? = null
    private var isFavorite: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)


        swipeRefresh = swipe_refresh_detail
        val intent = intent
        idEvent = intent.getStringExtra("id")
        idTeamHome = intent.getStringExtra("idHomeTeam")
        idTeamAway = intent.getStringExtra("idAwayTeam")
        progresbar = progresar_detail

        loadingShow()

        supportActionBar?.title = "Detail Match"
        this.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        favoriteState()
        val apiRequest = ApiRepository ()
        val gson = Gson ()
        matchpresenter = MatchDetailPresenter(this, apiRequest, gson)
        matchpresenter.getAwayLogo(idTeamAway)
        matchpresenter.getHomeLogo(idTeamHome)
        matchpresenter.getDetailMatch(idEvent)

    }


    override fun matchListShow(data: List<MatchActivity>) {
        matchdet.clear()
        matchdet.addAll(data)

        //detailmatch
        tvdetail_match_date.text = matchdet[0].dateEvent
//        tvdetail_match_date.text = matchdet.get(0).dateEvent
//            ?.let { DateHelper.formatDateToMatch(it) }

        //detailhome
        tvTeam_home_detail.text = matchdet[0].teamHome
        tvScore_home_detail.text = matchdet[0].scoreHome
        tvHome_goal_detail.text = matchdet[0].homeGoalDetail
        tvHome_shot_detail.text = matchdet[0].homeShot
        tvHome_gk.text = matchdet[0].homeKeeper
        tvHome_deffense.text = matchdet[0].homeDefense
        tvHome_mf.text = matchdet[0].homeMidfield
        tvHome_fw.text = matchdet[0].homeForward
        tvHome_sub.text = matchdet[0].homeSubstitute

        //detailAway
        tvTeam_away_detail.text = matchdet[0].teamAway
        tvScore_away_detail.text = matchdet[0].scoreAway
        tvAway_goal_detail.text = matchdet[0].awayGoalDetail
        tvAway_shot_detail.text = matchdet[0].awayShot
        tvAway_gk.text = matchdet[0].awayKeeper
        tvAway_deffense.text = matchdet[0].awayDefense
        tvAway_mf.text = matchdet[0].awayMidfield
        tvAway_fw.text = matchdet[0].awayForward
        tvAway_sub.text = matchdet[0].awaySubstitute

        loadingHide()

    }

    override fun showAwyLogo(data: List<Team>) {

        Glide.with(this).load(data[0].team).into(ivAway_detail)
        ivAway_detail.visible()
    }


    override fun showHomeLogo(data: List<Team>) {

        Glide.with(this).load(data[0].team).into(ivHome_detail)
        ivHome_detail.visible()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.favorite_match, menu)
        menuItem = menu
        setFavorite()
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                finish()
                true
            }
            add_fav_fragment -> {
                if (isFavorite) removeFromFavorite() else addToFavorite()

                isFavorite = !isFavorite
                setFavorite()
                true
            }

            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    private fun favoriteState() {
        database.use {
            val result = select(FavoriteItem.TABLE_MATCH)
                .whereArgs("(MATCH_ID = {id})",
                    "id" to idEvent as Any
                )
            val favorite = result.parseList(classParser<FavoriteItem>())
            if (!favorite.isEmpty()) isFavorite = true
        }
    }

    override fun loadingShow() {
        progresbar.visible()
    }

    override fun loadingHide() {
        progresbar.gone()
    }


    private fun addToFavorite() {
        try {
            database.use {
                insert(
                    FavoriteItem.TABLE_MATCH,
                    FavoriteItem.MATCH_ID to matchdet[0].idEvent,
                    FavoriteItem.MATCH_DATE to matchdet[0].dateEvent,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_TEAM to matchdet[0].teamHome,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_SCORE to matchdet[0].scoreHome,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_TEAM to matchdet[0].teamAway,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_SCORE to matchdet[0].scoreAway,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_ID to matchdet[0].idHomeTeam,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_ID to matchdet[0].idAwayTeam,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_GOAL to matchdet[0].homeGoalDetail,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_GOAL to matchdet[0].awayGoalDetail,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_SHOTS to matchdet[0].homeShot,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_SHOTS to matchdet[0].awayShot,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_GK to matchdet[0].homeKeeper,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_GK to matchdet[0].awayKeeper,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_FW to matchdet[0].homeForward,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_FW to matchdet[0].awayForward,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_MF to matchdet[0].homeMidfield,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_MF to matchdet[0].awayMidfield,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_DF to matchdet[0].homeDefense,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_DF to matchdet[0].awayDefense,
                    FavoriteItem.HOME_SUB to matchdet[0].homeSubstitute,
                    FavoriteItem.AWAY_SUB to matchdet[0].awaySubstitute)

            }
            swipeRefresh.snackbar("Added to favorite").show()
        } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException){
            swipeRefresh.snackbar(e.localizedMessage).show()
        }
    }

    private fun removeFromFavorite(){
        try {
            database.use {
                delete(
                    FavoriteItem.TABLE_MATCH, "(MATCH_ID = {id})",
                    "id" to matchdet.get(0).idEvent )
            }
            swipeRefresh.snackbar("Removed from favorite").show()
        } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException){
            swipeRefresh.snackbar(e.localizedMessage).show()
        }
    }

    private fun setFavorite() {
        if (isFavorite)
            menuItem?.getItem(0)?.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fav_white)
        else
            menuItem?.getItem(0)?.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fav_white_border)
    }


}
```

MatchDetailPresenter :

```
package com.example.riken.footballmatch.presenter

import com.example.riken.footballmatch.api.ApiRepository
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.api.TheSportDBApi
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.model.MatchResponse
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.model.TeamResponse
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.team.detmatch.MatcDetView
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync
import org.jetbrains.anko.uiThread

class MatchDetailPresenter (
    private val matchDetailView: MatcDetView,
    private val apiRepository: ApiRepository,
    private val gson: Gson) {

    fun getDetailMatch (idEvent: String?) {
        matchDetailView.loadingShow()

        GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main){
            val data = gson.fromJson(apiRepository.doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getMatchDetail(idEvent)).await(),
                MatchResponse::class.java)

            matchDetailView.loadingHide()
            matchDetailView.matchListShow(data.events)
        }
    }

    fun getAwayLogo (idTeam: String?) {
        matchDetailView.loadingShow()

        GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main){
            val data = gson.fromJson(apiRepository.doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getTeamLogo(idTeam)).await(),
                TeamResponse::class.java)

            matchDetailView.loadingHide()
            matchDetailView.showAwyLogo(data.teams)
        }

    }

    fun getHomeLogo (idTeam: String?) {
        matchDetailView.loadingShow()

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val data = gson.fromJson(
                apiRepository.doRequest(TheSportDBApi.getTeamLogo(idTeam)).await(),
                TeamResponse::class.java
            )

            matchDetailView.loadingHide()
            matchDetailView.showHomeLogo(data.teams)
        }
    }
}
```

HomeActivityTest :

```
package com.example.riken.footballmatch.view

import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions
import android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.riken.footballmatch.R.id.*
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class HomeActivityTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(HomeActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun testFootballMatchBehaviour() {

        delay()
        onView(withId(recycle_first)).
            check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(recycle_first))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(7))
        onView(withId(recycle_first))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(7, ViewActions.click()))

        onView(withId(tvdetail_match_date))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))

        onView(withId(ivHome_detail))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(tvTeam_home_detail))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(tvScore_home_detail))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))


        onView(withId(ivAway_detail)).
            check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(tvTeam_away_detail))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(tvScore_away_detail))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))

        onView(withId(add_fav_fragment))
            .perform(ViewActions.click())
        ViewActions.pressBack()

    }
    private fun delay(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000)
        }catch (e : InterruptedException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

}
```

DetailActivity line 108 :Glide.with(this).load(data[0].team).into(ivAway_detail)
MatchDetailActivity line 40 :  matchDetailView.showAwyLogo(data.teams)
HomeActivityTest line 40 :  onView(withId(tvTeam_home_detail)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

Answer (score 4):

This question has already been asked, please see: [You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity in relativelayout image using glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093730/you-cannot-start-a-load-for-a-destroyed-activity-in-relativelayout-image-using-g)

In conclusion, instead of using "***this***" in your activity

```
Glide.with(***this***).load(data[0].team).into(ivHome_detail)
        ivHome_detail.visible()
```

change "`this`" to "`getApplicationContext`" like so:

```
Glide.with(***getApplicationContext()***).load(data[0].team).into(ivHome_detail)
        ivHome_detail.visible()
```